# Angular2 - 1 way binded param

Tags: javascript, angular

When I use in my html template `{{param_name}}` it binds the `param_name` for the 2(two) directions. How do I use it only for one way binding?

Comment: can you please add an example? your template and, if possible, your component.

Comment: template: <SearchBox">{{mainTitle}}</SearchBox>
component: @Input() mainTitle;

Comment: Angular has only one-way binding. No idea why you think it's 2-way. You need a combination of property binding `[]` and event binding `()` (`[()]`) to get two-way binding.